# Define the values of an array of structures

Tags: c, microcontroller, structure

When I declare a typedef the following way:

```
typedef struct
{
  uint8 LastState;
  uint8 CurrentState;
  uint8 NextState;
  uint8 TaskEnabled;
  uint8 Counter;
  uint8 Status;
}SM_tstTaskStateStructure;
```

I try to define the content for the array I am trying to create the following way:

```
#define xInitDataTable  \
{IDLE,IDLE,IDLE,YES,TIMED7SEG,IDLE},   \
{IDLE,IDLE,IDLE,YES,TIMELED1,IDLE},   \
{IDLE,IDLE,IDLE,YES,TIMELED2,IDLE},   \
{IDLE,IDLE,IDLE,YES,TIMELED3,IDLE},   \
{IDLE,IDLE,IDLE,YES,TIMEBTN,IDLE},   \
{IDLE,IDLE,IDLE,YES,BASETIME,IDLE},   \
{IDLE,IDLE,IDLE,YES,FREQUPDATE,IDLE}
```

and then initialize it as an array of structures:

```
static const SM_tstTaskStateStructure   SM__astData[TASKMAX]=
{
    xInitDataTable  
};
```

Is this compiler specific? Softune compiler for Fujitsu mc allows me to initialize the array of structs this way, while Code Composer Studio does not. If so, is there any similar way to do this (using a define if possible)?

** These are only numeric values, no pointers or anything.

EDIT: Nevermind, Occurs with all members when trying to use a pre or post increment

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: What error does Code Composer show you?

Comment: expression must be a modifiable lvalue

Comment: and occurs in lines such as SM__astData[u8TaskID].Ctr--;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as `TASKMAX` is greater than 7, this initialization is perfectly standard.

> #### C11 (n1570), § 6.7.9 Initialization
>
> ```
> initializer:
>     assignment-expression
>     { initializer-list }
>     { initializer-list , }
> ```

If the error is printed when you increment your values, it is because `SM__astData` is declared with the `const` qualifier.

> #### C11 (n1570), § 6.5.3.1 Prefix increment and decrement operators
>
> The operand of the prefix increment or decrement operator shall have atomic, qualified,
>   or unqualified real or pointer type, and shall be a modifiable lvalue.

If you want to do such operations, use the following declaration:

```
static /* const */ SM_tstTaskStateStructure   SM__astData[TASKMAX]=
{
    xInitDataTable  
};
```

Comment: AH you are right, I was using a declaration syntax I copied from a function pointer struct array.